# Interesting card combinations

Tags: mathematics, word, calculation-puzzle, combinatorics, probability

In a normal pack of playing cards (without jokers), the probabilities of the following events are the same:

(1) Drawing a set of 4 different cards (irrespective of its **color** *and* **suit**) - let us call it as set X

(2) Drawing another set of  4 different cards (irrespective of its **color** *and* **suit** and different from those of X) - let us call it as set Y and

(3) Drawing another set of  4 different cards (irrespective of its **color** *and* **suit** and different from those of X **and** Y) - let us call it as set Z

As the problem statement is too broad, I try to narrow it down by saying:

The sets of cards are drawn at different times from a full pack of cards and if the cards in each of those sets are **not** *consecutive* ones, then find the possible card denominations in each set.

Comment: They could be the same word. That would easily solve it.

Comment: @Apep, well, you spotted it. Edited my question.

Comment: @Deusovi Kinda gotcha you noticed, corrected in my edited question.

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay Can a two digit card (10) and an ace - 1/13 be counted as an answer?

Comment: @prog_SAHIL, well hyphenated( that is two words combined) type words are expected. Though your logic and answer suit as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could have so many answers, so I'll submit one that I think's kind of interesting.

The probabilities of drawing a

> prime-numbered card (2, 3, 5, 7)

and a

> "non-numbered" card (A, J, Q, K)

are the same, both having a chance of

> 4/13

Comment: Yes, you got one set( or rather a pair) of words correct!

Comment: +1 I was thinking of a *strange*-numbered set instead of your first one. This answer leaves less room for debate on the value of *a ce*rtain card.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is way too broad.  For instance, in addition to all of the answers already given, I give you

> One-eyed (3)

and

> mustachioed king (3)

This question should have more definition in it, or at least some hints in the puzzle to provide a singular answer.

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

> Odd and Even

Explanation:

> Aces are frequently considered to be 1 OR 11, however, it is still only one card, giving us A, 3, 5, 7, 9 for Odd cards, and 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 for Even cards. Each card value has 4 instances in a normal pack, so the probabilities of drawing one from either set is the same, provided the cards are replaced once drawn.

Comment: good attempt, though  requiring some assumptions to prove your point!

Answer (score 0):

Are the words you're looking for

> 'right-side-up' and 'upside-down'? Depending on how you're holding the deck, you could draw your card upside down. (I don't mean "face-down", but rather "with the symbols on the card flipped".)

Comment: well, your logic applies well for all, except for **Diamonds** I am afraid!

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer might be that your odds of drawing a

> red-faced (as in the color of the King, Queen, or Jack's face)card are equal to your chances of drawing a black-faced card since there are 6 of each in every deck of cards.

And I know that

> regardless of the suit but this is based on the color of the person's face on the card...but the question is too wide open.